# "Coalesce" multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a simple query

`SELECT row FROM table WHERE id=my_id`

and I want a row with a NULL instead of an empty row if `my_id` isn't found, I can use `coalesce`

```
COALESCE( (SELECT row FROM table WHERE id=my_id), NULL)
```

What do I do if my query returns multiple columns and I want a row of NULLs?

```
SELECT row1,row2,row3 FROM table WHERE id=my_id
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `coalesce` behavior (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)? `coalesce` is used to replace a missing (`NULL`) value with somethingelse...

Comment: @BrunoZamengo Yes, because `SELECT (SELECT row FROM table WHERE id=my_id) IS NULL` returns true. At least that's the way I understand it. Is that correct?

Comment: Upon reflection, I've put the coalesce in the title into quotation marks. Coalesce itself is possibly not a solution, but I think it describes what I want quite well.

Comment: A bit hard to tell you... we would need some sample data from your table at least

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30152720/7635569) (since original question talks about a stored procedure output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a pseudo table with `UNNEST` for your parameter and do a left outer join:

```
SELECT t.row1, t.row2, t.row3 
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[my_id]) i LEFT OUTER JOIN table t ON t.id = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to simply search the table three times

```
SELECT 
COALESCE( (SELECT row1 FROM table WHERE id=my_id), NULL),
COALESCE( (SELECT row2 FROM table WHERE id=my_id), NULL),
COALESCE( (SELECT row3 FROM table WHERE id=my_id), NULL)
```